# Placing augmented matrix into RREF

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the solution set to the following system of three linear equations
in three unknowns over C by first placing its augmented matrix into
RREF.

how would you do this question?

$$ix_1+ x_2 − x_3 = 0$$

$$−ix_2 + x_3 = 1$$

$$x_1 + x_2 − 2x_3 = 0$$

Comment: how do you work with the i in the matrix

Comment: Since your matrix is over $\mathbb{C}$, $i$ is treated like any other number. The exact same rules apply if you were working in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: We create that matrix as follows,

$$ix_1+ x_2 − x_3 = 0$$

$$−ix_2 + x_3 = 1$$

$$x_1 + x_2 − 2x_3 = 0$$

$$ \Rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
i & 1 & -1 \\
-i & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & -2 
\end{bmatrix}
$$